# Android drawing texture with OpenGL ES 2.0 slow on some devices

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es-2.0, textureview

In my Android 4.3 application, I would like to load a texture from a local png onto a TextureView. I do not know OpenGL and I am using the code from the [GLTextureActivity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/tests/HwAccelerationTest/src/com/android/test/hwui/GLTextureViewActivity.java) hardware acceleration test. I am pasting also the loading texture part here:

```
    private int loadTexture(int resource) {
        int[] textures = new int[1];

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        checkGlError();

        int texture = textures[0];
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        checkGlError();

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, resource);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, bitmap, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
        checkGlError();

        bitmap.recycle();

        return texture;
    }
```

I am running the code in two devices: *Nexus 7* and Galaxy Nexus phone, and I notice a huge speed difference between the two. For *Nexus 7*, the drawing part takes about 170 ms, although for the *Galaxy Nexus* it takes 459 ms. The most time consuming operation is the loading of the texture and especially the `texImage2D` call. I have read that there are devices with chips that are slow on `texImage2D`-`texSubImage2D` functions but how can someone tell which are those devices and how can I avoid to use those functions to achieve the same result?

Thank you in advance.

// EDIT: the `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)` call seems to also be significantly slower in the phone device. Why is this happening? How could I avoid it?

Comment: FWIW, I added a `glTexImage2D()` timing test to Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika).  Mostly to have a simple way to compare a 512x512 RGBA texture upload across devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading textures on each frame redraw? That's just not right - you should load textures only once before main rendering loop. You won't get instant textures loading even on the fastest possible device - you load resource, decode bitmap from it and then load it to GPU. This takes some time.

Comment: I have modified the loadTextures() method, so that the operations are done at initialization time and the only call I make on each frame redraw is GLUtils.texImage2D, because I need to be drawing several PNGs, so I am drawing a different bitmap every time. Is this wrong? How else could I do it? How come it is faster when frames are coming from the camera or media player on a SurfaceTexture for instance?

Comment: `texImage2D()` is very resource-consuming operation. It processes source bitmap and uploads it into GPU. It is far from an 'instant' operation. There is no need to change your `loadTexture()` method, it is correct. You can have as many textures as can fit in GPU. Just make an array or collection of integers then store all your texture IDs (returned from `loadTexture()`) before main rendering loop and then only pass necessary IDs to shader via uniform.